# Does it makes sense to wrap JS util functions in a class if I transition to TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, architecture

Maybe this question is slightly weird, but I really want to get some points of view on this.

I have developed a web project using JavaScript. It has modular architecture (also, the major number of code is wrapped in classes, except of some specific cases) and one of the modules is called `tokenizer`. Also, I have a directory called `utils` which contains a file with util functions for the `tokenizer` module.

This file looks like this:

```
import SymbolStringRepresentation from '@utils/enums/symbol';
import TokenType from '@utils/enums/tokenType';
import OperatorType from '@utils/enums/operatorType';
import AssociativityType from '@utils/enums/associativityType';
import * as regexp from '@utils/regexp';
import {UnknownTokenTypeError} from '@error/customErrors';

/**
 * Checks whether provided token is a left parenthesis.
 *
 * @param {Token} token Token to check.
 * @returns {boolean} True if the token is a left parenthesis.
 *                    False otherwise.
 */
function isLeftParenthesis(token) {
    return token.getValue() === SymbolStringRepresentation.LEFT_PARENTHESIS;
}

/**
 * Checks whether provided token is a right parenthesis.
 *
 * @param {Token} token Token to check.
 * @returns {boolean} True if the token is a right parenthesis.
 *                    False otherwise.
 */
function isRightParenthesis(token) {
    return token.getValue() === SymbolStringRepresentation.RIGHT_PARENTHESIS;
}

/**
 * Checks whether the provided token is an operator.
 *
 * @param {Token} token Token to check.
 * @returns {boolean} True if the provided token is an operator.
 *                    False otherwise.
 */
function isOperator(token) {
    return token.getType() === TokenType.OPERATOR;
}

/**
 * Checks whether the provided token is a unary operator.
 *
 * @param {Token} token Token to check.
 * @returns {boolean} True if the provided token is a unary operator.
 *                    False otherwise.
 */
function isUnaryOperator(token) {
    return token.getValue().type === OperatorType.UNARY;
}

/**
 * Checks whether the provided token is a binary operator.
 *
 * @param {Token} token Token to check.
 * @returns {boolean} True if the provided token is a binary operator.
 *                    False otherwise.
 */
function isBinaryOperator(token) {
    return token.getValue().type === OperatorType.BINARY;
}

/**
 * Checks whether the provided token is right-associative.
 *
 * @param {Token} token Token to check.
 * @returns {boolean} True if the provided token is right-associative.
 *                    False otherwise.
 */
function isRightAssociative(token) {
    return token.getValue().associativity === AssociativityType.RIGHT;
}

/**
 * Checks whether the provided token is a literal.
 *
 * @param {Token} token Token to check.
 * @returns {boolean} True if the provided token is a literal.
 *                    False otherwise.
 */
function isLiteral(token) {
    return token.getType() === TokenType.LITERAL;
}

/**
 * Checks whether the provided token is a literal or
 * an operator with right associativity.
 *
 * @param {Token} token Token to check.
 * @returns {boolean} True if the provided token is a literal or
 *                    an operator with right associativity.
 */
function isLiteralOrOperatorWithRightAssociativity(token) {
    return (
        isLiteral(token) ||
        (isOperator(token) && isRightAssociative(token))
    );
}

/**
 * Determines the token type of provided mathematical expression member.
 *
 * @param {string} expressionMember The expression member to determine the type of.
 * @returns {string} The token type of the expression member.
 * @throws {UnknownTokenTypeError} If the type of the expression member is unknown.
 */
function getTokenTypeOf(expressionMember) {
    const matchesRegexp = createTestRegexpFunction(expressionMember);

    if (matchesRegexp(regexp.digits)) {
        return TokenType.LITERAL;
    } else if (matchesRegexp(regexp.parenthesis)) {
        return TokenType.PARENTHESIS;
    } else if (matchesRegexp(regexp.operator) || matchesRegexp(regexp.letters)) {
        return TokenType.OPERATOR;
    }

    throw new UnknownTokenTypeError(`Unknown token type of the member: ${expressionMember}`);
}

/**
 * Determines whether provided expression members are of
 * the same token type.
 *
 * @param {string} member1 First expression member.
 * @param {string} member2 Second expression member.
 * @returns {boolean} True if the expression members have the same
 *                    token type. False otherwise.
 */
function isSameTokenType(member1, member2) {
    return getTokenTypeOf(member1) === getTokenTypeOf(member2);
}

/**
 * Checks whether the provided type is literal or parenthesis.
 *
 * @param {string} type Token type to check.
 * @returns {boolean} True is the provided token type is a literal
 *                    or parenthesis. False otherwise.
 */
function isTypeOfLiteralOrParenthesis(type) {
    return (
        type === TokenType.LITERAL
        || type === TokenType.PARENTHESIS
    );
}

/**
 * Checks whether the provided type is function or operator.
 *
 * @param {string} type Token type to check.
 * @returns {boolean} True is the provided token type is a function
 *                    or an operator. False otherwise.
 */
function isOfTypeOperator(type) {
    return type === TokenType.OPERATOR;
}

/**
 * Helper higher-order method for creating a function for regexp testing.
 *
 * @param {string} expression The expression to test the regexp against.
 * @returns {function(RegExp): boolean} True if the char matches the regexp. False otherwise.
 */
function createTestRegexpFunction(expression) {
    return function (regexp) {
        return regexp.test(expression);
    };
}

export {
    isLeftParenthesis,
    isRightParenthesis,
    isOperator,
    isUnaryOperator,
    isBinaryOperator,
    isRightAssociative,
    isLiteral,
    isLiteralOrOperatorWithRightAssociativity,
    getTokenTypeOf,
    isSameTokenType,
    isTypeOfLiteralOrParenthesis,
    isOfTypeOperator
};
```

Imports `SymbolStringRepresentation`, `TokenType`, `OperatorType`, `AssociativityType` are already re-written using TypeScript enums (previously they looked like plain JavaScript objects).

Does it makes sense to create a 'wrapper' class like `TokenizerUtilFunctions` and make all these functions static class methods to maintain the concept of wrapping everything in classes (+interfaces, enums) (assuming I start using TypeScript to provide a better code structure and reliability)? Or is it better to leave it as it is and just add types for function params and return values?

Comment: Switching to typescript is by itself not a reason to start wrapping everything in classes. In your case you would already benefit from being able to remove all those pesky jsdoc comments :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd keep them outside of a class.

Class methods are not removed by tree-shaking while standalone functions are.